# How to see if two categorical variables are indepedent or not when number of categories differs alot?

Tags: machine-learning, anova, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, predictive-models

I have one categrical variable with ~10,000 levels, and one categorical response with 3 classes,both have length ~200,000, and I want to see if they are independent or not, i.e, I want to know if I can remove this variable when predicting the response. But when I apply chi square test, the p-value is always extremely small, indicating that they are depedent. I wonder if this is due to the lagre difference between number of categories (3 vs ~10,000) or they are indeed depedent. Do you have any suggestions of what should I do here?
Appreciate and help!

Comment: I guess  the test is probably inappropriate [see eg http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3900058/] :" The value of the cell expecteds should be 5 or more in at least 80% of the cells, and no cell should have an expected of less than one (3). This assumption is most likely to be met if the sample size equals at least the number of cells multiplied by 5. Essentially, this assumption specifies the number of cases (sample size) needed to use the χ2 for any number of cells in that χ2. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in the number of categories won't matter at all.

You have a huge sample size (200000); even a small amount of dependence will be significant.